# Why is wxWidgets erring out when I follow the instructions?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am following the [Hello World tutorial](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/WxSmith_tutorial:_Hello_world) for `WxSmith` using CodeBlocks 20.03 and wxWidgets 3.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.  This is later confirmed to also happen in Windows 10 using the same CodeBlocks and wxWidgets.  I have it working up to this point:

> Search for border size and change it from 5 to 0.

So far, the `Resource` view is as follows:

[image]

Moving on:

> Since we will also use sizers to manage items added into wxPanel, we have to repeat the addition of wxBoxSize into wxPanel. After the sizer is in its place, switch back into the Standard tab on the palette and add a wxStaticText control.

What I understand is that I have to add another `wxBoxsizer` into the `wxPanel` object, and put a `wxStaticText` object into it.  I then build the code using the gear button, which gives no error.  Then I run it with the play button, and it throws an error:

[image: img]

I would like to ask what I have done wrong.  This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjxG4nygQOM) doesn't have the outer `wxBoxSizer` and it works.

[image: img3]

I would like to ask what I have done wrong, and how I can make it work according to the tutorial?

Further scouring the web shows someone running into this exact problem more than 9 years ago [here](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=36867).  This is failing code from me:

```
/***************************************************************
 * Name:      testMain.cpp
 * Purpose:   Code for Application Frame
 * Author:     ()
 * Created:   2022-12-27
 * Copyright:  ()
 * License:
 **************************************************************/

#include "wx_pch.h"
#include "testMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(testFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(testFrame)
const long testFrame::ID_STATICTEXT1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_PANEL1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(testFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(testFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

testFrame::testFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(testFrame)
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(960,320), wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    StaticText1 = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(120,60), 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(StaticText1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Button1 = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(Button1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Panel1->SetSizer(BoxSizer2);
    SetSizer(BoxSizer2);
    Layout();
    BoxSizer1->Add(Panel1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);
    BoxSizer1->Fit(this);
    BoxSizer1->SetSizeHints(this);

    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

testFrame::~testFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(testFrame)
    //*)
}

void testFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void testFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}
```

And this is the working code from that link:

```
#include "wx_pch.h"
#include "testMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(testFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(testFrame)
const long testFrame::ID_STATICTEXT1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_PANEL1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(testFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(testFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

testFrame::testFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(testFrame)
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    SetClientSize(wxSize(491,450));
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    StaticText1 = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(StaticText1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Button1 = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(Button1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Panel1->SetSizer(BoxSizer2);
    BoxSizer2->Fit(Panel1);
    BoxSizer2->SetSizeHints(Panel1);
    BoxSizer1->Add(Panel1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);
    SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    Layout();

    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

testFrame::~testFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(testFrame)
    //*)
}

void testFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void testFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}
```

Comparing the two, the root of the problem is from these 4 lines (working code on the right):

[image: img4]

The code works after commenting out the 4 lines on the left, and copying the ones on the right over.  Now it appears that these lines set the relationships between elements.  Could someone explain to me what they mean (right and wrong), and what I can do to get the correct ones generated?  I followed the instructions the best I can, and apparently something was not done right.  The working code has THE SAME graphical layout as mine.  Only the generated code is different in crucial places.  I couldn't find any more detailed video or instructions that could help getting it right in the first place.

Comment: for starter - you posted an image with the error. Please remove the image and just copy and paste an error exactly as it appears in the dialog.

Comment: Because you basically cut off people that are legally blind or just doesn't want to click on the image for security reason.

Comment: And second - I for one would like to see an actual code that the tool generated for you. Could you please post it. And again - not a screenshot, the actual text plaese.

Comment: Hello @Igor, I have attached the folder with everything in it.  I didn't post the code because showing all of them would make the post very messy.

Comment: just put the source of one cppfile inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the first `swBoxSizer` and the `wxPanel`, this is what is shown in the preview window:

[image: img]

The tiny object induces me to set the size to the `wxPanel` object to make it visible and easy to work on.  However this triggers a change in the generated code.  The panel's size is no longer `wxDefaultSize` but `wxSize(960,320)` as seen in the failing code above.  In order to avoid this, I must not change the size and use the tool `Insert new widgets into current selection` which looks like this:

[image: img]

After that, another `swBoxSizer` and `swStaticText` are added sequentially.  `swButton` is added last using the original `Insert new widget by pointing with mouse` tool.

[image: img]

This is the working code that is generated:

```
#include "wx_pch.h"
#include "testMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(testFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(testFrame)
const long testFrame::ID_STATICTEXT1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_PANEL1 = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long testFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(testFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(testFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

testFrame::testFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(testFrame)
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    StaticText1 = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(StaticText1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Button1 = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(Button1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Panel1->SetSizer(BoxSizer2);
    BoxSizer2->Fit(Panel1);
    BoxSizer2->SetSizeHints(Panel1);
    BoxSizer1->Add(Panel1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);
    BoxSizer1->Fit(this);
    BoxSizer1->SetSizeHints(this);

    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

testFrame::~testFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(testFrame)
    //*)
}

void testFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void testFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}
```

This is a pitfall that can discourage beginners trying to learn the framework.  I hope this will help anybody who finds this post.